# ADO pipeline MSBuild@1 can't find .Net Core 7 under ubuntu-latest

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on a Azure DevOps pipeline and I'm getting an error where MSBuild can't find .Net Core 7 when using the ubuntu-latest image. This project builds successfully using `windows-latest`.

Here are the relavent pieces of my pipeline.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  # vvmImage: windows-latest
  # vmImage: windows-2022
  # Old App building on windows ltssc 2019
  #vmImage: windows-2019

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: 'Build'
    jobs:
      - job: 'Build'
        displayName: 'Build the solution'

        steps:
          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
            inputs:
              packageType: 'sdk'
              version: 7.0.x
              includePreviewVersions: true

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            inputs:
              command: 'restore'
              projects: '**/*.csproj'

          - task: MSBuild@1
            inputs:
              solution: '**/*.sln'
```

It generates this error...

```
(GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) -> 
  /usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1232,5): error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v7.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Api/Api.csproj]
```

Comment: I just fought with Azure pipelines with the same error - in my case the build process was in a container so it was a bit different from your issue.  I see you have UseDotNet@2 in the first step and DotNetCoreCLI@2 in the second.  Might be worth changing the second to UseDotNet@2.